# Chess. What is it called when a pawn takes a pawn by being passed

Tags: chess

What is it called when a pawn takes a pawn by being passed by another pawn?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to when a pawn (On the fourth rank of the opponent's field) has a pawn move two squares (said pawns first move of the game, landing directly adjacent to the first), then you are referring to *En Passant* (being French for In Passing). This ruling came about after a change was made to the game of chess, for pawns were once only allowed to move up one square at a time, making the game slower and allowing for more possible pawn captures; after a time, a modification to pawn movement allowed them to move two squares on their (independent) first move, some liked this change, while others did not. Eventually a compromise was reached, and En Passant entered into the rules of chess, and continues to be a possibility to this day.

Comment: The *immediacy* of eligibility for such a capture really should be mentioned. And a direct quote of the relevant rule, in addition, would make this answer worthy of an up-vote.